# How to make a full width image with fixed height in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to make a full width image with fixed height. So I write the following code
in html

```
<div class="marquee">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <img class="img-marquee" src="img/image1.jpg" alt="image 1">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <img class="img-marquee" src="img/image2.jpg" alt="image 2">
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

in CSS I write the following code

```
.marquee {
    height: 75vh;
}

.img-marquee {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

The result is full width image but not with the same height of the marquee which is 75vh. so my question how to do that in css by using bootstrap framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with :

```
.img-marquee {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
width:100%
display:block
position:absolute #optional
background: url('your .jpg') repeat scroll 0% 0% / 100% auto transparent;
```